# How to lock a hashmap during refresh?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a static `HashMap` that is populated on application startup, and refreshed daily.

How can I ensure that during refresh no other thread can access the map?

```
@ThreadSafe
public class MyService {

   private static final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
   private MyDao dao;

   public void refresh(List<Object> objects) {
       map.clear();
       map.addAll(dao.findAll()); //maybe long running routine
   }

   public Object get(String key) {
       map.get(key); //ensure this waits during a refresh??
   }
}
```

Should I introduce a simple `boolean lock` that is set and cleared during `refresh()`? Or are there better choices? Or is the `synchronized` mechanism a way to go?

Comment: I think boolean lock is the way to go.

Comment: Why not concurrentHashMap?

Comment: Use a lock is a simple way to do that and can work. If you want to put more design in it, i think that the Semaphor principle will be a good choice.
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/semaphores.html

Comment: Would concurrent hashmap ensure that no `get()` is possible between clear+addAll? I don't think so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a volatile map and reassign it after population:

```
public class MyService {

   private static volatile Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
   private MyDao dao;

   public void refresh(List<Object> objects) {
       Map<String, Object> newMap = new HashMap<>();
       newMap.addAll(dao.findAll()); //maybe long running routine
       map = newMap;
   }

   public Object get(String key) {
       map.get(key); //ensure this waits during a refresh??
   }
}
```

It is non blocking, the assignment from `newMap` to `map` is atomic and ensures visibility: any subsequent call to `get` will be based on the refreshed map.

Performance wise this should work well because volatile reads are almost as fast as normal reads. Volatile writes are a tiny bit slower but considering the refreshing frequency it should not be an issue. If performance matters you should run appropriate tests.

Note: you must make sure that no external code can get access to the `map` reference, otherwise that code could access stale data.

Comment: THAT is indeed a great solution, will go for this.

Comment: This works because we assume that only one thread is writing, right? Otherwise I'd expect possible lost updates.

Comment: @atamanroman, since the refresh calls clear in the code of the question, this is the intended behavior.

Comment: @atamanroman it works regardless of the number of threads - a thread calling `get` will always see the latest (complete) update of the map.

Answer (score 1):

Please dont make the map-attribute static, all accessor-methods are non-static.

If `get` should wait or `refresh` mutates the map instead of completely exchanging it, then ReadWriteLock is the way to go. ConcurrentMap if the collection is mutated but `get` should not wait.

But if `refresh` completely replaces the map, i may suggest different non-waiting implementations:

1) do the long running operation outside the synchronized block

```
public void refresh() {
       Map<String, Object> objs = dao.findAll();
       synchronized(this) {
         map.clear();
         map.addAll(objs); 
       }
}

public Object get(String key) {
    synchronized(this) {
       return map.get(key); 
    }
}
```

The readers are not run in parallel, but else perfectly valid.

2) use a volatile non-final reference of an nonchanged collection:

```
// guava's ImmutableHashMap instead of Map would be even better
private volatile Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

public void refresh() {
    Map<String, Object> map = dao.findAll();
    this.map = map;
}
```

3) AtomicReference of nonchanged collection

Instead of a volatile reference also a AtomicReference may be used. Probably better because more explicit than the easily missed volatile.

```
// guava's ImmutableHashMap instead of Map would be even better
private final AtomicReference<Map<String, Object>> mapRef = 
    new AtomicReference<>(new HashMap<String, Object>());

public void refresh() {
    mapRef.set(dao.findAll());
}

public Object get(String key) {
    return map.get().get(key); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using synchronized block or a ReadWriteLock would be a better choice here. This way, you wouldn't have to change anything in the calling code.

You could also use a concurrentHash, but in that case, for aggregate operations such as putAll and clear, concurrent retrievals may reflect insertion or removal of only some entries.

Answer (score 0):

It's weird you need to `clear()` then `addAll()` for such a global map. I smell your problem needs to be resolved properly by a `ReadWriteLock` protected double buffering.

Anyway, from a pure performance point of view, on normal server boxes with total number of CPU core < 32, and much more read than write, `ConcurrentHashMap` is probably your best choice. Otherwise it needs to be studied case by case.