# How to refresh HashMap while clients read from it

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a static `HashMap` that is initialized on server startup. Clients initialize their data from this map when they login.
Now I need to refresh this map, but clients can login and get data from this map at the same time.

Can I change reference of map like below while they read? 
I cant use `synchronized` because they can read in at the same time and only one thread is writing.

```
   public void refresh() {
       Map<String, Object> newMap = prepareData();
       map = newMap;
   }
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28147889/how-to-lock-a-hashmap-during-refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume that "refresh" means that you want to replace all entries in the hashmap with a fresh set loaded from (say) a file.

If the set of keys in the new mapping is a superset of the keys in the original mapping, AND if you application doesn't care if clients can set part of the old mapping and part of the new mapping at the same time, then you could use a `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of a `HashMap`, and replace the entries with a sequence of `put` calls.

However, if keys are (or could be) different, or if the update needs to be atomic from the client's perspective then a `ConcurrentHashMap` is not going to work.  Instead, you need to declare `map` as a `volatile` and implement your `refresh()` method as per your question.

As you point out, using `synchronized` (or a single-writer-multiple-reader lock) is liable to lead to a concurrency bottleneck.

---

Note: using a `volatile` is likely to give better performance than using a `ConcurrentHashMap` even in the cases where the latter is a viable solution.

Comment: If I need to use LinkedHashMap so everyone can read in same order then volatile LinkedHashMap will solve my problem right?

Comment: Yes it will.  The `volatile` allows you to do the replacement of the map as an atomic thread-safe operation.  It would work for any standard `Map` type.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your map needs to be declared as `volatile` in order to ensure that each thread has the last version of it, then here is how you could proceed:

```
public void refresh() {
    synchronized (MyClass.class) {
        Map<String, Object> newMap = prepareData();
        map = Collections.unmodifiableMap(newMap);
    }
}
```

And your map would be declared as below:

```
private static volatile Map<String, Object> map = ...
```

Comment: I don't need synchronized statement for clients right? They can read in parallel in this case

Comment: that's right, the Map still needs to be thread safe so I made it unmodifiable thanks to Collections.unmodifiableMap since immutable objects are thread safe

Comment: This would only stop concurrent writes. You need to sync read access on the same lock in order to stop reading from occurring while you are writing. You'd need to sync the clients too. And, you should lock on the map itself, not on some random 'myclass' object. Also, you should clear the map and repopulate not replace it with a new object otherwise your clients will never know that it's changed.

Answer (score 1):

If it's ok that clients have stale data, then all you need to do is create a new map and point your static reference at it. If a new client comes along while you're doing this then they get the stale data and no harm is done, if they turn up after the switch (reassignment) to the new values has occurred then they will get the new values. Job done.

If it's not ok then you will also, probably, have to inform other clients that existed before the update about the change. In which case you want to use the observer pattern for the updates. In this pattern it's fine if the client connects during the update, because they will be updated as soon as possible after the update is complete.

BTW: in all cases, you really shouldn't be using 'static' for anything. It'll only lead to problems down the line. Rather, create a non-static singleton that holds the map and inject that into your clients/services/whatever.