# synchronization of method acessing the concurrent hashMap

Tags: java

I am working on a problem statement where it is required to update the object(from database) stored as cache in map after very 5 min

It is done:

```
     Map <String, String>hashMapParam = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    
     if (!this.hashMapParam.isEmpty() && this.hashMapParam.containsKey(key)) 
            {
                returnValue = this.hashMapParam.get(key);
                
                 if(isThresholdReached(returnValue))
                 {
                    refreshParam(logger); //loads data from db
                    
                 }
               
             }   
private void refreshParam() 
{
 this.hashMapParam.clear(); 
//loads data from db loadData(); }
```

Do I need to synchronize method **refreshParam** as I am getting null values when testing with multiple threads even after using concurrentHashMap?

The implementation works fine if I synchronize this method.

Answer (score 3):

`!this.hashMapParam.isEmpty()` is redundant check.

The reader thread would have tried to read a value *after* the map is cleared (`hasMapParam.clear()`) and *before* the entries are loaded from the DB. Hence, your approach does not seem correct. At some point in time, your `hashMapParam` is empty.

A ConcurrentHashMap enables multiple threads writing to a map concurrently. It doesn't help you when you have two operations on the map like you do (clear and load).

Synchronizing the `refreshParam` method will not stop the other threads from reading from the map when the refresh is in progress.

You have to synchronize on the `hashMapParam` and the callers must also do the same. This defeats the whole point of using a ConcurrentHashMap.

I suggest you:

1. Make the concurrent hash map *volatile*.
2. Create a new ConcurrentHashMap with newly loaded data from DB
3. Reassign the reference to the concurrent hash map with the new reference.

   `this.hashMapParam = <new_concurent_hash_map_instance_with_latest_mappings>`

See: [How to refresh HashMap while clients read from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36621891/how-to-refresh-hashmap-while-clients-read-from-it)

---

*(You haven't shown us how you load the data into the map)*

**If you don't want to synchronize the refresh method...**

Do you want to load all the items in one go? Are there integrity requirements across multiple entries? Can you load the entries without clearing the map? In this case, you have to find the deleted entries and remove it from the map.

Comment: yes i want to clear all the entries when the threshold is reached and load all the items in map in one go

Comment: Are the other writers into the map apart from the refresh method?

Comment: no,there are no other writer but multiple readers

Comment: Then there is no reason to use a concurrent hash map. See the linked post in my answer.

Comment: i have another question, will it work with multithreads if i put   Map <String, String>hashMapParam = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    
     if (!this.hashMapParam.isEmpty() && this.hashMapParam.containsKey(key)) 
            {
                returnValue = this.hashMapParam.get(key);
                
                 if(isThresholdReached(returnValue))
                 {
                    refreshParam(logger); //loads data from db
                    
                 }
               
             } in synchronized block ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is it synchronized on? synchronized on map?

Comment: I meant if i am using volatile map, do i need to synchronize map get operation if a thread is trying to read while a map is being updated?

Comment: No you do not (assuming there is only one writer thread). The map will not be updated per se. You will create a new map and switch the references. See points 2 and 3

Comment: so, in that case i need to clear my old map as it will still create issues of null pointer exception while reading the map,right?

Comment: You will not clear your old map. You leave it as it is and it will be garbage collected. 
`newHashMapParam = <load_from_db>`
`hashMapParam = newHashMapParam` (reference changed to point to new map).

Comment: Thank you but in that case the reading thread will get stale data if write operation is being performed by writer thread during refresh

Comment: Yes. Till the assignment happens(`hashMapParam = newHashMapParam`), the readers will read the old data.

Comment: then this approach will not help me as i want updated data

Comment: I do not understand what you are looking for. Why are you being bothered for the other threads to read the value from old map when the data is *being* loaded. If you always want the new data you shouldn't be having a cache in the first place.